# How to plot 3D path data as a ribbon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, ribbon

I have scatter data `X1,Y1,Z1` in 3D, which I can plot as

```
a=1; c=1; t=0:100;
X1 = (a*t/2*pi*c).*sin(t);
Y1 = (a*t/2*pi*c).*cos(t);
Z1 = t/(2*pi*c);
scatter3(X1,Y1,Z1);
% or plot3(X1,Y1,Z1);
```

The points define a 3D path. How do I make this into a ribbon plot, similar to the one below?

With delaunay triangulation I can plot it as a surface:

`tri = delaunay(X1,Y1);`
`h = trisurf(tri, X1, Y1, Z1);`

But `ribbon` does not give the desired result:

`ribbon(Y1)`

The figure below shows what I am after.

[image: ,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ribbon` function can only accept 2D inputs because it uses the 3rd dimension to 'build' the ribbon.

One way to achieve a 3D ribbon is to build series of `patch` or `surface` between each point and orient them properly so they look continuous.

The following code will build a ribbon around any arbitrary 3D path defined by an `(x,y,z)` vector. I will not explain each line of the code but there are plenty of comments and I stopped for intermediate visualisations so you can understand how it is constructed.

```
%% Input data
a=1; c=1; t=0:.1:100;
x = (a*t/2*pi*c).*sin(t);
y = (a*t/2*pi*c).*cos(t);
z = t/(2*pi*c);

nPts = numel(x) ;

%% display 3D path only
figure;
h.line = plot3(x,y,z,'k','linewidth',2,'Marker','none');
hold on
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
```

[image: Base path]

```
%% Define options
width = ones(size(x)) * .4 ;

% define surface and patch display options (FaceAlpha etc ...), for later
surfoptions  = {'FaceAlpha',0.8 , 'EdgeColor','k' , 'EdgeAlpha',0.8 , 'DiffuseStrength',1 , 'AmbientStrength',1 } ;

%% get the gradient at each point of the curve
Gx = diff([x,x(1)]).' ;
Gy = diff([y,y(1)]).' ;
Gz = diff([z,z(1)]).' ;
% get the middle gradient between 2 segments (optional, just for better rendering if low number of points)
G = [ (Gx+circshift(Gx,1))./2 (Gy+circshift(Gy,1))./2 (Gz+circshift(Gz,1))./2] ;

%% get the angles (azimuth, elevation) of each plane normal to the curve

ux = [1 0 0] ;
uy = [0 1 0] ;
uz = [0 0 1] ;

for k = nPts:-1:1 % running the loop in reverse does automatic preallocation
    a = G(k,:) ./ norm(G(k,:)) ;
    angx(k) =  atan2( norm(cross(a,ux)) , dot(a,ux))  ;
    angy(k) =  atan2( norm(cross(a,uy)) , dot(a,uy))  ;
    angz(k) =  atan2( norm(cross(a,uz)) , dot(a,uz))  ;
    
    [az(k),el(k)] = cart2sph( a(1) , a(2) , a(3) ) ;
end
% compensate for poor choice of initial cross section plane
az = az + pi/2 ; 
el = pi/2 - el ;


%% define basic ribbon element
npRib = 2 ;
xd = [ 0 0] ;
yd = [-1 1] ;
zd = [ 0 0] ;

%% Generate coordinates for each cross section

cRibX = zeros( nPts , npRib ) ;
cRibY = zeros( nPts , npRib ) ;
cRibZ = zeros( nPts , npRib ) ;
cRibC = zeros( nPts , npRib ) ;

for ip = 1:nPts
    % cross section coordinates.
    csTemp = [ ( width(ip) .* xd )  ; ... %// X coordinates
               ( width(ip) .* yd )  ; ... %// Y coordinates
                               zd    ] ;   %// Z coordinates
    
    %// rotate the cross section (around X axis, around origin)
    elev = el(ip) ;
    Rmat = [ 1     0           0     ; ...
             0 cos(elev)  -sin(elev) ; ...
             0 sin(elev)   cos(elev) ] ;
    csTemp = Rmat * csTemp ;
    
    %// do the same again to orient the azimuth (around Z axis)
    azi = az(ip) ;
    Rmat = [ cos(azi)  -sin(azi) 0 ; ...
             sin(azi)   cos(azi) 0 ; ...
               0            0    1 ] ;
    csTemp = Rmat * csTemp ;
    
    %// translate each cross section where it should be and store in global coordinate vector
    cRibX(ip,:) = csTemp(1,:) + x(ip) ;
    cRibY(ip,:) = csTemp(2,:) + y(ip) ;
    cRibZ(ip,:) = csTemp(3,:) + z(ip) ;
end

%% Display the full ribbon
hd.cyl = surf( cRibX , cRibY , cRibZ , cRibC ) ;
set( hd.cyl , surfoptions{:} )
```

[image: 3D ribbon, contruction lines]

Now you have your graphic object contained in one surface object, you can set the options for the final rendering. For example (only an example, explore the `surface` object properties to find all te possibilities).

```
%% Final render
h.line.Visible = 'off' ;
surfoptionsfinal  = {'FaceAlpha',0.8 , 'EdgeColor','none' , 'DiffuseStrength',1 , 'AmbientStrength',1 } ;
set( hd.cyl , surfoptionsfinal{:} )
axis off
```

[image: final render]

---

Note that this code is an adaptation (simplification) of the code provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28177448/3460361) (to that question: [Matlab: “X-Ray” plot line through patch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27275906/3460361)).

This method allows to draw an arbitrary cross section (a disc in the answer) and build a surface which will follow a path. For your question I replaced the `disc` cross section by a simple line. You could also replace it with any arbitrary cross section (a disc, a square, a potatoid ... the sky is the limit).

---

Edit

### Alternative Method:

Well it turns out there is a Matlab function which can do that. I first discarded it because it is meant for 3D **volume** visualisations, and most ways to call it require gridded input (`meshgrid` style). Luckily for us, there is also a calling syntax which can work with your data.

```
% Same input data
a=1; c=1; t=0:.1:100;
x = (a*t/2*pi*c).*sin(t);
y = (a*t/2*pi*c).*cos(t);
z = t/(2*pi*c);

% Define vertices (and place in cell array)
verts = {[x.',y.',z.']};
% Define "twistangle". We do not need to twist it in that direction but the
% function needs this input so filling it with '0'
twistangle = {zeros(size(x.'))} ;
% call 'streamribbon', the 3rd argument is the width of the ribbon.
hs = streamribbon(verts,tw,0.4) ;

% improve rendering
view(25,9)
axis off
shading interp;
camlight
lighting gouraud
```

Will render the following figure:
[image]

For additional graphic control (over the edges of the ribbon), you can refer to this question and my answer: [MATLAB streamribbon edge color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31065113/3460361)