Plot line with varying thickness (z coordinate data)
I have a dataset with x, y and z data. I want to visualize it in a way to show z height variance as well using matplotlib.
PS: I'm trying to visualize racing tracks for analysis
This is my current code and results, but it doesn't show anything about the Z data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.12)
ax.axis('off')

# creating track line
ax.plot(lap.telemetry['X'], lap.telemetry['Y'] ,
        color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=5, zorder=0)


I've also tried playing around with the trisurf plotting, which gives depth, but doesn't distinguish between them
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', )
ax.plot_trisurf(lap.telemetry['X'], lap.telemetry['Y'], lap.telemetry['Z'],
        color='white', alpha=1)


Edit: I've tried plotting the line instead of the surface
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', )
ax.plot(lap.telemetry['X'], lap.telemetry['Y'], lap.telemetry['Z'],
        color='black', alpha=1 )

And that shows the line in z axis instead of showing depth, so looks like the track has overlapping parts


Why not plot the line (not a surface) in 3D?

Hi @jared
I assume you meant this:
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', ) ax.plot(lap.telemetry['X'], lap.telemetry['Y'], lap.telemetry['Z'],         color='black', alpha=1 )
But doesn't give the proper result, there is a lot of over lap due to the z values

What overlap is there? Include it in your question. That might be a data issue, not a matplotlib issue.

sure @jared I've added it to the post

What's overlapping? Are you saying it looks to be overlapping because of the orientation?

The overlap seems to be an issue of viewers perspective. If you rotate the 3d view you should be able to avoid overlap. Anyhow, is 3d visualization mandatory? Else it might be suitable to generate an x-y plot with a color coded z.

I think you should use a LineCollection.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

t = np.linspace(0, 12, 1201)
x = np.sin(0.3*t)
y = np.sin(0.5*t)*(1+0.05*t)
z = np.sin(t)
thicc = z+1.5 # from 0.5 to 2.5

# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880037/2749397 for explanation
segments = np.stack((np.c_[x[:-1],x[1:]],np.c_[y[:-1],y[1:]]), axis=2)
lc = LineCollection(segments, linewidths=thicc)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()


thanks @gboffi this works best for now

@Liya Thank you for recognizing my effort. I have to say that using a colormap instead of a varying thickness to represent z allows, using a colorbar, to show more clearly the underlying z values.

like I said, I'm trying to visualize f1 race tracks, it definitely would've been more helpful to see the depth and difference in elevation through the track. I'm still trying to play around with the code, will switch to colorbar if I'm not satisfied with the result

@Liya Sorry, I forgot the context of your question. If you are mapping the width of the track, using linewidth seems OK to me... BTW, there is also LineCollection3D, if you remove the x-z and y-z planes and find the right scaling and the right camera position you may get something nice. I remember that LineCollection3D is not as flexible as its 2D counterpart, but right now I can't say if it supports linewidth. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63392225/2749397 that could be useful
